# popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView: hangs when switching to another application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, menu

I am working on a dockless application (`LSUIElement` true). The application pops up a menu when the user clicks on the corresponding `NSStatusItem`, or when a keyboard shortcut is used.

My problem is that all methods to pop up a menu programmatically hang whenever the user switches to another application (using ⌘-TAB) without dismissing the menu first. I have tried `popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView:`, `popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:`, and the corresponding method on `NSStatusItem` (`popUpStatusItemMenu:`).

If the user dismisses the menu with the ESC key everything works fine, but if the user switches to a different application, the above-mentioned methods never return (they seem to run synchronously and return when the menu is dismissed). The application does not crash, and there are a couple of tricks to regain control (invoking exposé, or clicking on any `NSStatusItem` which pops up a menu).

The problem disappears if the application has a dock icon (i.e. setting `LSUIElement` to false).

This is the code popping up the menu when the keyboard shortcut is used:

```
[mainMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem:[mainMenu itemAtIndex:0]
                        atLocation:[NSEvent mouseLocation]
                            inView:nil];
```

And this is the code popping up the menu when the `NSStatusItem` is clicked:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:[statusItem menu]];
}
```

The `mouseDown:` method is in the custom `NSView` attached to the `NSStatusItem`.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks for your help.

### Update

The problem is also linked to the application being activated (I use `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];` before showing the menu, or in some cases it is not possible to navigate the menu with the keyboard).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the problem is due to the application activation and popUpMenu happening in the same event cycle. I have found a workaround, described in more details in [this post](http://www.osomac.com/2011/04/06/using-nsmenu-in-a-lsuielement/).

Is summary, you need to activate the application first (using `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];`), and pop up the menu after, making sure this happens in a new event cycle: you can achieve this using a NSTimer to trigger the menu.

```
- (void) someMethod {
    // Some code
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(showMenu) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    //Some other code
}

- (void) showMenu {
    // This will show the menu at the current mouse position
    [aMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem:[mainMenu itemAtIndex:0] atLocation:[NSEvent mouseLocation] inView:nil];
}
```

Comment: If I just sleep for 0.01 instead of schedule timer, will it also work?